# Método não aceita passagem de null a parâmetro

Tags: java, parâmetros

**Tenho o seguinte método:**

```
public String insereRegistro(int tipo, String data, String horario, String historico,
                                  int veiculo, double km, int cliente, int solicitante,
                                  String finalizado) {
   ...
}
```

Como faço para que o método aceite o valor null ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode passar null em todos o parâmetros que não sejam tipos primitivos.

Se quer fazer o mesmo em parâmetros do tipo primitivo substitua-os pelas respectivas classes:

```
public String insereRegistro(Integer tipo, String data, String horario, String historico,
                             Integer veiculo, Double km, Integer cliente, Integer solicitante,
                             String finalizado) {
   ...
}
```